# Adding class for only 1st element of array of custom field with same values in php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom field with key `Slider Image` for a page in WordPress. This key accepts multiple values. [admin dashboard for the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouiw6.png)

Here's the `php` code for displaying the aforesaid in the front-end:

```
   $slider_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Slider Image', false);
   if( count( $slider_image ) != 0 ) {
     foreach($slider_image) {
       echo '<li class="">...</li>';
     }
   }
```

This outputs the expected

```
<li class="">...</li>
<li class="">...</li>
<li class="">...</li>
.
.
.
```

I want only the 1st `li` to have class of `active`. How can I do this? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886610/display-1st-paragraph-within-advanced-custom-fields), I think, comes close to the answer.

Comment: What do you need the class for? What about the pseudo class selector `:first-child`?

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead?

Comment: I'm making a slider whereby the page must load with at least one `<li class="active">...</li>`

Comment: In PHP you would set `$cls = 'active'` echo that and after first loop set it `''`.

Comment: How can I use a `for` loop here?

Comment: If I set `foreach` loop after setting the `$cls = 'active'`, the whole code repeats the first image element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in two ways, either by PHP with the following approch

```
if(count($slider_image)!= 0) {
   $flag = 1;

   foreach($slider_image as $img) {

      if($flag==1) {
         echo '<li class="active">...</li>';
         $flag++; 
      }
      else {
         echo '<li class="">...</li>';
      }
   }
}
```

or using jQuery using the following way

```
$('#parentID li:first').addClass('aaaa');
```

where parentID is is the id of the parent element of the li elements.

Comment: I get the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'` on the `foreach` line

Comment: Thank you, this and ArtisticPhoenix's answers solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop instead if it's number index:

```
if( false != ($len = count( $slider_image ))) {
    for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
       //$value = $slider_image[$i];
       $class = $i==0 ? 'active' : '';
       echo '<li class="'.$class.'">...</li>';
    }
}
```

If it's not you can do this with foreach

```
$slider_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Slider Image', false);
if( count( $slider_image ) != 0 ) {
   $first = key($slider_image); //get the key at the current position (the first one)
   foreach($slider_image as $key=>$value) {
       $class = $key==$first ? 'active' : '';
       echo '<li class="'.$class.'">...</li>';
  }
}
```

If you want to get fancy you could do a `do/while` loop like this:

```
$slider_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Slider Image', false);
if( count( $slider_image ) != 0 ) {
   do{
       $class = !isset($class) ? 'active' : '';
       //$value = current($slider_image);
       echo '<li class="'.$class.'">...</li>';
       next($slider_image);
   }while(current($slider_image));
}
```

Simple.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work. I needed to put the `$slider_image` in the `li` element, but when I do that, there's a array to string conversion error, so I did `echo '<li class="'.$class.'"><div style="background: url('.$value.') ;" ></div></li>';`

Comment: How to access the value for the other types of loops is in comments.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$slider_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Slider Image', false);
if( is_array( $slider_image ) )
{
  $cls = 'active';
  foreach($slider_image as $img) 
  {
    echo '<li class="' . $cls . '">...</li>';
    $cls = '';
  }
}
```

Even better you do it in PHP style as embedded language:

```
if( is_array( $slider_image ) )
{
  $cls = 'active';
  foreach($slider_image as $img)
  {
?>
    <li class="<?php echo $cls;?>"><img src="<?php echo $img?>"></li>
<?php
    $cls = '';
  }
}
```

However, if you need this class in JavaScript, I would set it also in JavaScript before slider initialization.

```
if(!document.querySelector('ul#mylist>li.active'))
  document.querySelector('ul#mylist>li:first-child').classList.add('active');
```

Comment: receive a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' ` on the foreach($slider_image) line

Comment: @Sai No, I've tested before posting it. You have an error in *your* code not setting `as $variable`.